# How to change the img of a cloned div onClick

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

Right now I have a lovely code (that was initially for flowing snowflakes) that lets cloned divs fall from the top of the window, to the bottom and repeat. The thing is that I want the content to change on click. However, this is not yet working.

I know how to change content of a div without it being cloned, but I have serious trouble figuring out how to do the same with one div being cloned within the code.

Anyone have any tips what I should do, even a hint in which direction to go. I'm clueless.

This is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4yaxvt7h/

the javascript:

```
function changeImage(){
    document.getElementById('toChange').src='https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/19/56/6e195649034f042d1dea5230234570a8.gif';
   }



// Array to store our Snowflake objects
  var snowflakes = [];

  // Global variables to store our browser's window size
  var browserWidth;
  var browserHeight;

  // Specify the number of snowflakes you want visible
  var numberOfSnowflakes = 15;

  // Flag to reset the position of the snowflakes
  var resetPosition = false;

  // Handle accessibility
  var enableAnimations = false;
  var reduceMotionQuery = matchMedia("(prefers-reduced-motion)");

  // Handle animation accessibility preferences 
  function setAccessibilityState() {
    if (reduceMotionQuery.matches) {
      enableAnimations = false;
    } else { 
      enableAnimations = true;
    }
  }
  setAccessibilityState();

  reduceMotionQuery.addListener(setAccessibilityState);

  //
  // It all starts here...
  //
  function setup() {
    if (enableAnimations) {
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", generateSnowflakes, false);
      window.addEventListener("resize", setResetFlag, false);
    }
  }
  setup();

  //
  // Constructor for our Snowflake object
  //
  function Snowflake(element, speed, xPos, yPos) {
    // set initial snowflake properties
    this.element = element;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.scale = 1;

    // declare variables used for snowflake's motion
    this.counter = 0;
    this.sign = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1;

    // setting an initial opacity and size for our snowflake
    this.element.style.opacity = 1;
  }

  //
  // The function responsible for actually moving our snowflake
  //
  Snowflake.prototype.update = function () {
    // using some trigonometry to determine our x and y position
    this.counter += this.speed / 5000;
    this.xPos += this.sign * this.speed * Math.cos(this.counter) / 40;
    this.yPos += Math.sin(this.counter) / 40 + this.speed / 30;
    this.scale = .5 + Math.abs(10 * Math.cos(this.counter) / 20);

    // setting our snowflake's position
    setTransform(Math.round(this.xPos), Math.round(this.yPos), this.scale, this.element);

    // if snowflake goes below the browser window, move it back to the top
    if (this.yPos > browserHeight) {
      this.yPos = -50;
    }
  }

  //
  // A performant way to set your snowflake's position and size
  //
  function setTransform(xPos, yPos, scale, el) {
    el.style.transform = `translate3d(${xPos}px, ${yPos}px, 0) scale(${scale}, ${scale})`;
  }

  //
  // The function responsible for creating the snowflake
  //
  function generateSnowflakes() {

    // get our snowflake element from the DOM and store it
    var originalSnowflake = document.querySelector(".snowflake");

    // access our snowflake element's parent container
    var snowflakeContainer = originalSnowflake.parentNode;
    snowflakeContainer.style.display = "block";

    // get our browser's size
    browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    // create each individual snowflake
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSnowflakes; i++) {

      // clone our original snowflake and add it to snowflakeContainer
      var snowflakeClone = originalSnowflake.cloneNode(true);
      snowflakeContainer.appendChild(snowflakeClone);

      // set our snowflake's initial position and related properties
      var initialXPos = getPosition(50, browserWidth);
      var initialYPos = getPosition(50, browserHeight);
      var speed = 5 + Math.random() * 40;

      // create our Snowflake object
      var snowflakeObject = new Snowflake(snowflakeClone,
        speed,
        initialXPos,
        initialYPos);
      snowflakes.push(snowflakeObject);
    }

    // remove the original snowflake because we no longer need it visible
    snowflakeContainer.removeChild(originalSnowflake);

    moveSnowflakes();
  }

  //
  // Responsible for moving each snowflake by calling its update function
  //
  function moveSnowflakes() {

    if (enableAnimations) {
      for (var i = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
        var snowflake = snowflakes[i];
        snowflake.update();
      }      
    }

    // Reset the position of all the snowflakes to a new value
    if (resetPosition) {
      browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

      for (var i = 0; i < snowflakes.length; i++) {
        var snowflake = snowflakes[i];

        snowflake.xPos = getPosition(50, browserWidth);
        snowflake.yPos = getPosition(50, browserHeight);
      }

      resetPosition = false;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(moveSnowflakes);
  }

  //
  // This function returns a number between (maximum - offset) and (maximum + offset)
  //
  function getPosition(offset, size) {
    return Math.round(-1 * offset + Math.random() * (size + 2 * offset));
  }

  //
  // Trigger a reset of all the snowflakes' positions
  //
  function setResetFlag(e) {
    resetPosition = true;
  }
```

html

```
<div id="snowflakeContainer">
  <div class="snowflake"><img src="element1.png" 
</div>
```

css

```
body{
  background-color: black;
}

  #snowflakeContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
  }

  .snowflake {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }


  img{
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

any tips are super welcome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several different problems here. First, your CSS sets `pointer-events: none;` for all `.snowflake` elements. This will stop any clicks from triggering, so you have to remove it if you want mouse interactivity.

Second, your `changeImage()` function uses `document.getElementById('toChange')` to get the element to change the source of. No such element exists and even if it did, that would mean that clicking on any of the snowflakes would just change the source of that one image. You need to reference the snowflake that you clicked on. An easy way to do this is by passing `this` as an argument to the function in the onclick attribute:

HTML:

```
<div class="snowflake"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/7/70/Random.png/revision/latest?cb=20161221030547" onclick="changeImage(this)"></div>
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(img) {
    img.src = 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/19/56/6e195649034f042d1dea5230234570a8.gif';
}
```

Finally, your JSFiddle is configured to delay execution of the JavaScript until after the DOM is ready. This means that the code will be wrapped in a callback function, and therefore the `changeImage()` function will no longer be in the global scope. This makes it inaccessible to the elements that want to call it in their handlers (the snowflakes). Because you are already listening for the DOMContentLoaded event on your own, you can just change the code to execute normally and it should work. Click on the dropdown that says "JavaScript + jQuery 3.2.1" above your JS code and change the load type to any "No wrap" option and it should work.

Comment: You really are a hero. I thought way too hard about it, should have looked closer. Thank you!